# jQuery - Make tooltip get 2 img alts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I want to use images in my table headers.

Every image has assigned alt to it.

How can I make get this jQuery code to show tooltip with alt of row and column?(Row:Column format)

At this moment it looks like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/G38nx/33/

Code:

```
$('td').each(function () {
    var myIndex = $(this).index() + 1;
    var myTitle = $(this).closest('tr').find('th').text();
    var myTitle2 = $(this).closest('td').find('th').text();

    myTitle2 += $('td:first-child th:nth-child(' + myIndex + ')').children("img").attr("alt");
    $(this).attr('title', myTitle2);
    myTitle += ":";
    myTitle += $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + myIndex + ')').children("img").attr("alt");
    $(this).attr('title', myTitle);

    $(this).tooltip({
        show: false,
        hide: false
    });
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't use <th> in the whole table, only for the header row. That makes both styling and JavaScript easier. One could include the <thead> and <tbody> elements also. Furthermore, the <img> are missing closing tags. But you did a good job trying yourself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this :

```
$('td').each(function () {
    var myIndex = $(this).index() + 1;

    //I took the first sibling th, and took its alt attribute
    var myTitle += $(this).siblings('th').children("img").attr("alt");
    myTitle += ":";
    myTitle += $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + myIndex + ')').children("img").attr("alt");
    $(this).attr('title', myTitle);

    $(this).tooltip({
        show: false,
        hide: false
    });
});
```

[Check this Fiddle for a working example!](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/G38nx/35/)

Comment: @LaveLoos Thanks for the feedback! You'd better post your comment on the question, as it's more about the question itself, plus the OP will be notified of your comment ;)

Comment: You're right, fixed that. The 'nice solution' is still for you though :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, easiest way to do this is have your title element blank.
Have content already generated on the page inside a hidden div. 
Then when you initialize tool-tip in jQuery provide id of hidden help content.

Step 1

```
<div title=''  id="x">Show tool tip over this element</div>
```

Step 2

```
<div style="visibility:hidden"> 
<div id="y">What ever the content you want to be shown as tool tip</div> 
</div>
```

Step 3

```
$( "#x" ).tooltip({ track: true, content:function() {  return $( '#y' ).html(); } });
```